# Find the basis of a subspace of the space of polynomials with real coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to find a basis for the subspace $W$ of the space of polynomials with real coefficients, where $W:= \{ p(x) |p(x)=p(-x)\}$.

If there is a basis which is the subset of $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,...\}$, then it cannot contain $x^k$ where $k$ is an odd number.

I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: The set you're looking concerns just the even powers, as the subspace in question concerns even functions. $\{1,x^2,x^4, \dots\}$ could be a basis you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that if $\displaystyle p(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k$ then $\displaystyle p(-x)=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^ka_kx^k$ and hence $$p(x)=p(-x)\iff a_k=(-1)^ka_k \; \forall 0\leq k \leq n \iff a_k=0 \text{ for $k$ odd}$$

Hence any polynomial in $W$ is of the form $\displaystyle p(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_{2k}x^{2k}$ so the set $\{1,x^2,x^4,\dots\}$ is a spanning family.

As this set is also linearly independent (because a linear combination $\sum_{k=0}^n x^{2k}a_{2k}$ is zero iff each coefficient is zero) we have that $\{1,x^2,x^4,\dots\}$ is actually a basis for $W$.